# React-Native form validations

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Which is the best approach to do form validations. I'm currently using native-base and I need to show inline messages for userName and password. For example: 'User name is required' or 'Password is required'

The following code represents the form view.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  StyleSheet,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import { Item, Label, Input } from 'native-base';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      username: null,
      password: null,
      versionNumber:'N/A' };
  }

  async saveItem(item, selectedValue) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }

  userLogin() {
    if (!this.state.username || !this.state.password) return;

    fetch('https://mobiletest.myapp.com/api/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.saveItem('id_token', responseData.userId);
        Alert.alert('Login Success!');
        Actions.InspectionListGenerator();
      })
      .done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BackgroundImage>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View>
            <Image style={styles.logo} resizeMode='contain' source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')} />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.transformDataTitle}> Data</Text>
          <Text style={styles.transformDataSubTitle}>  Asset Management</Text>
          <View style={styles.form}>

             <Item floatingLabel style={StyleSheet.flatten(styles.floatingLabel)}>
              <Label>Username</Label>
                 <Input 
                         autoCapitalize="none"
                         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
                         value={this.state.username}
                     />

            </Item>

            <Item floatingLabel style={StyleSheet.flatten(styles.floatingLabel)}>
              <Label>Password</Label>
              <Input 
                         onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                         value={this.state.password}
                         secureTextEntry={true}
                     />

            </Item>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonWrapper} onPress={this.userLogin.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}> LOGIN </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Text style={styles.forgotYourPassword}>FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</Text>

            <Text style={styles.versionNumber}>v N/A</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </BackgroundImage>
    );
  }
}

class BackgroundImage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={require('../assets/images/login-bg.png')}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}>

        {this.props.children}

      </Image>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'cover'
  },
  logo: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 8,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#ffffff'
  },
  buttonWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#054e6e',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    width: 300
  },
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  form: {
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  image: {
    margin: 10
  },
  floatingLabel:{
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  transformDataTitle: {
    fontSize: 35,
    margin: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: "oxygen-regular"
  },
  transformDataSubTitle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: "oxygen-regular"
  },
  forgotYourPassword:{
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#054e6e'
  },
  versionNumber:{
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

Comment: As a `redux` fan I would recommend `redux-form`. I know it requires some knowledge of `redux` and a bunch of boilerplate to set up, but it makes your life so much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using Redux you could add two paramaters to your state, one called hasError which is a boolean and tell us if there's an error in the form and the other called errorMessage which contains the error message to show.

```
this.state = { 
      username: null,
      password: null,
      versionNumber:'N/A',
      hasError: false,
      errorMessage: ''
};
```

And then when the user submit you need to check for each input if it's correct or not, if not you need to set the state to : hasError = true and the errorMessage = The message of the error
For example:

```
if(this.state.username.length<=3)
   this.setState({hasError: true, errorMessage: "Username need to be longer than 3 characters");
```

And then at the bottom of the form you could add a text with a red color that will show the error text if there's any, like this

```
{this.state.hasError ? <p>this.state.errorMessage</p> : null}
```

Don't forget to set it back to false when the user change the content of the input.

And also don't send the HTTP request unless the this.state.hasError or any variable you used to check for errors is set to false.